# odata breeze: Collection of ComplexType: - "TypeError: Cannot call method '_createInstanceCore…"

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, odata, breeze, complextype

I would like to use Breeze to work with an OData Service. I spent hours trying to get this running, but I did not find a solution, so I really hope anybody can help!? (I just started to use breeze - so I am sorry if I am missing something "obvious" here.)

What I would like to do is to use a Collection of sub-objects (ComplexType). I.e. I would like my entity class to have a collection property like this:

```
public List<Address> addresses { get; set; }
```

(Address is no entity which is persisted on its own in a DB collection, but a simple class with some properties (ComplexType))

The server is a MVC4 WebAPI ODATA Service that is based on Entity Framework Code First POCO classes that are persisted in a MongoDB database.

In the browser I get the following error, when the breeze library tries to read the ODATA metadata from the server (it does not even query the example collection, it has an error before that):

```
[Q] Unhandled rejection reasons (should be empty): 
["TypeError: Cannot call method '_createInstanceCore…://localhost:56936/scripts/breeze.debug.js:236:26"]
```

Is there any way to get this running?

Thank you!

My client code looks like this:

```
var serverAddress = "http://localhost:56936/odata";
breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstances({ dataService: "OData" });
var manager = new breeze.EntityManager(serverAddress);

var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from("BreezeExample");
manager.executeQuery(query).then(querysucceeded).fail(queryfailed);

function querysucceeded(data) {
    console.log("querysucceeded");
    data.results.forEach(function (item) {
        //...
    });
}

function queryfailed(e) {
    console.log("!!! queryfailed");
    console.log(e);
}
```

The Model is as follows:

```
[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
public class ExampleClass : MongoEntity
{
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string loginEmail { get; set; }
    public bool? active { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Address> addresses { get; set; } //THIS DOES NOT WORK CLIENT SIDE - WHY?
}

public class Address
{
    public string place { get; set; }
    public string street { get; set; }
    public string houseNumber { get; set; }
    public string postalCode { get; set; }
}
```

If I query the ODATA metadata using the browser (`http://localhost:56936/odata/$metadata`), I get this result:

```
<edmx:Edmx xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/06/edmx" Version="1.0">
  <edmx:DataServices xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" m:DataServiceVersion="3.0" m:MaxDataServiceVersion="3.0">
    <Schema xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm" Namespace="MvcWebRole1.Models.MongoDB.Entities">
      <EntityType Name="ExampleClass">
        <Key>
          <PropertyRef Name="Id" />
        </Key>
        <Property Name="loginEmail" Type="Edm.String" />
        <Property Name="active" Type="Edm.Boolean" />
        <Property Name="addresses" Type="Collection(MvcWebRole1.Models.MongoDB.Entities.Address)" Nullable="false" />
        <Property Name="Id" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" />
      </EntityType>
      <ComplexType Name="Address">
        <Property Name="place" Type="Edm.String" />
        <Property Name="street" Type="Edm.String" />
        <Property Name="houseNumber" Type="Edm.String" />
        <Property Name="postalCode" Type="Edm.String" />
      </ComplexType>
      <EntityContainer Name="Container" m:IsDefaultEntityContainer="true">
        <EntitySet Name="BreezeExample" EntityType="MvcWebRole1.Models.MongoDB.Entities.ExampleClass" />
      </EntityContainer>
    </Schema>
  </edmx:DataServices>
</edmx:Edmx>
```

If I query the BreezeExample collection (`http://localhost:56936/odata/BreezeExample`) I get this:

```
{
    odata.metadata: "http://localhost:56936/odata/$metadata#BreezeExample",
    value: [
    {
        loginEmail: "loginEmail1",
        active: true,
        addresses: [
        {
            place: "place",
            street: "street",
            houseNumber: "77",
            postalCode: "123"
        },
        {
            place: "place2",
            street: "street",
            houseNumber: "77",
            postalCode: "123"
        }
        ],
        Id: "1"
    },
    {
        loginEmail: "loginEmail2",
        active: true,
        addresses: [
        {
            place: "place",
            street: "street",
            houseNumber: "77",
            postalCode: "123"
        },
        {
            place: "place",
            street: "street",
            houseNumber: "77",
            postalCode: "123"
        }
        ],
        Id: "2"
    }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to partially fix the problem by doing the following:

First of all, it turns out that Breeze doesn't understand the `Collection(MvcWebRole1.Models.MongoDB.Entities.Address)` type; So it cannot create the appropriate `dataType` property. This might be the reason while you get the error. 
I changed the type to something like Edm.Self.Address.

The other change that I made was in the `parseCsdlComplexProperty` function. I added one more line which fixed everything.

```
    var dp = new DataProperty({
        nameOnServer: csdlProperty.name,
        complexTypeName: complexTypeName,
        isScalar: csdlProperty.isScalar, // LINE ADDED
        isNullable: false
    });
```

Just to recap, my metada file contains the following snippet

```
{
    "name": "ColourByType",
    "key": {
      "propertyRef": {
        "name": "Id"
      }
    },
    "property": [
      {
        "name": "Id",
        "type": "Edm.Int32",
        "nullable": "false",
        "annotation:StoreGeneratedPattern": "Identity"
      },
      {
        "name": "Options", // This is the list that holds the instance of my complex type
        "type": "Edm.Self.ColourByOption", // This is the complex type that is stored in the list
        "isScalar": false 
      }
    ]
  }
```

I'm sure that this solution is not ideal, but it worked for me.

I've asked a similar question; so you might want to keep on eye on it, as well

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21258015/breezejs-metadata-is-missing-information-about-complex-properties

Comment: You can look at this page to see how you can import metadata from a script http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/load-metadata-script